# Could not resolve Android dependency due to Bad Gateway: 502

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

On the 8th of December I started having issues to run an Android project (Created with the Flutter framework) that had already been published to the Google Play and never had issues when compiling before.

The error I was getting was the following:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.



   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[18.0.0].
     Required by:


         project :app > project :firebase_analytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0


         project :app > project :firebase_analytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.0
         project :app > project :firebase_analytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:18.0.0
         project :app > project :firebase_analytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.0
         project :app > project :firebase_analytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.0





      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'.


               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

So I started digging and found out that my recent changes were not the issue. And it seems that the Bintray download center was sunset on the 1st of December (google.bintray.com)

Since I'm using a old version of some of the Firebase packages it seems that this link has been shutdown and now I'm not able to compile my application.

Flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-arm, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
  throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
  throw new GradleException("versionCode not found. Define flutter.versionCode in the local.properties file.")

}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
  throw new GradleException("versionName not found. Define flutter.versionName in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.reliqium.reliqium"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
           if (System.getenv()["CI"]) { // CI=true is exported by Codemagic
               storeFile file(System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PATH"])
               storePassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
               keyAlias System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_ALIAS"]
               keyPassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_PASSWORD"]
           } else {
                keyAlias System.getenv("RELIQIUM_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("RELIQIUM_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
                storeFile file(System.getenv("HOME") + "/keystores/reliqiumapp.keystore")
                storePassword System.getenv("RELIQIUM_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
           }
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:7.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:7.0.1'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4"
}
```

The version of the Flutter Firebase packages are the following:

- [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore): ^0.16.0+1
- [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics): ^7.0.1
- [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth): ^0.20.1
- [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core): ^0.7.0
- [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics): ^0.4.0+1
- [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links): ^0.7.0
- [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging): ^8.0.0-dev.14
- [firebase_remote_config](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config): ^0.6.0
- [firebase_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage): ^7.0.0

I know, these are outdated versions of the Firebase packages (For multiple reasons it's not viable to upgrade them to their next versions)

The issue seems to be with the Firebase Analytics package. I have tried to remove it but then I get a similar error for the Firebase Cloud Firestore package which is required for the application.

Please can someone help me with this. I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to solve this issue and I need to compile the app to launch a new version soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading my Gradle version to v4.1.0

android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
  ...
}
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

(EDIT):
You also need a couple more things:

1. Remove the jcenter() from your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ...
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral() // add this
    // jcenter() // remove this
  }
}
...

allprojects {
  repositories {
     google()
     mavenCentral()// ADD THIS
     // jcenter() // REMOVE THIS
  }
}
```

2. Switch minifyEnabled & shrinkResources to false in the app/build.gradle:

```
android {
  ... 
  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      minifyEnabled false // ADD THIS
      shrinkResources false // ADD THIS
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem that version of **com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[18.0.0]** is not specified strictly and gradle have to find possible versions but google.bintray.com is down - no version listing available

Base flow of resolving this issue

1. Find what version is - this **[18.0.0]** mean it has versions range
   [Gradle Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html)
2. Search for versions of *com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base* to find which you could set [Maven search](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement). We have versions 18.0.0 - 18.0.3
3. The [ and ] symbols indicate an inclusive bound with only one version - so consider take exactly 18.0.0 [Gradle Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html)
4. Constrain your transitive dependency with maximum possible version 18.0.0

Edit your project **app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  constraints {
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base') {
        version {
            strictly '18.0.0'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Sergey. Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried what you mention and I'm still getting the same error. I also tried v18.0.1, v18.0.2, v18.0.3 but I get another strange error: `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/15/fr5h9d_144zb9zxszj52pqk40000gn/T/gradle8553077257355350225.bin offset 429012 exists? true`

Comment: perform flutter clean & possible remove gradle cache ~/.gradle

Comment: Upgrading Gradle to v4.1.0 solved my issue. Thanks for your help Sergey

Comment: @Migalv could you please mark my answer as Accepted and upvote it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hello @Sergey, I tried your solution and it didn't work out. I tried what I answered and it allowed me to run the application in debug mode. But now for some reason, the app gets frozen when opening in release mode. This is starting to be very critical for my company and we are looking for a freelance that could help us solve this issue as soon as possible. If you are interested and think you could solve this problem please get in contact with me through this email: alvarez.lesmes.miguel@gmail.com